# How to add new field to Array element in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, element

I need add new field to Array element in MongoDB, this is my collection:

```
doc1={
    "Name":"Dat",
    "Academic level":[
            {
            "Primary school": "Binh Tri 2",
            "Classification":"A"
            },
            {
            "Junior high school": "Binh Tri Dong",
            "Classification":"B"
            },
            {
            "High school": "Mac Dinh Chi",
            "Classification":"C"
            },
    ]
}
```

I want to add "Achievement" for all Array element, example:

```
doc1={
    "Name":"Dat",
    "Academic level":[
            {
            "Primary school": "Binh Tri 2",
            "Classification":"A",
            "Achievement":true
            },
            {
            "Junior high school": "Binh Tri Dong",
            "Classification":"B",
            "Achievement":true
            },
            {
            "High school": "Mac Dinh Chi",
            "Classification":"C",
            "Achievement":true
            },
    ]
}
```

I tried many solutions on the internet but it didn't work, please help me, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `$set` the field in an update with aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "Academic level.Achievement": true
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OGhClKOxcer)

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't think I have to use $map for my problem

Comment: @ĐạtTrần oh yes you are right! with some more experiment it can actually be done in a much simpler way!